# Onedrive API with python : path and upload

Tags: python, excel, rest, api, onedrive

I use python and I would like to upload a file in a specific folder on Onedrive
I have an existing XLSX file in the folder data/project1/sample.xlsx
and I want to copy this file in the folder copy/all_files/sample.xlsx
(if the file already exists it can be replaced)

I execute the code bellow and the file is uploaded on my root folder)

```
returned_item = client.item(drive='me', id='root').children['sample.xlsx'].upload('sample.xlsx')
```

but I can't specify a specific folder to upload my file
Could you please tell me how it's possible ?

if I specify path like that, it doesn't work

```
returned_item = client.item(drive='me', id='root').children['copy/all_files/sample.xlsx'].upload('sample.xlsx')
```

I used the code and configuration from here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/quick-start

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it, you just need to change `id` to `path` in the client.item()

So assuming the folder is called `all_files`, you can upload it like this:

```
returned_item = client.item(drive='me', path='all_files').children['sample.xlsx'].upload('sample.xlsx')
```